# Xamarin.iOS Linker removes members in class needed for reflection

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, linker, xamarin.ios

In a Xamarin project, I set the linker behaviour to "Link all references". When doing that, assemblies get optimized by removing unused members. One problem, it's not actually aware that we need them for reflection. I know there is the Preserve attribute that we can put to tell the linker to keep all symbols in the class, but what if the assembly is a DLL or just not an iOS project (doesn't reference the monotouch assemblies, and can't). Is there a way I can set all classes from a library to "preserve", ignore it, or only set certain classes to be optimized (reverse PreserveAttribute) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@SharpMobileCode gave a very good explanation but there are also two other ways to solve this.

1. Use an XML file and use `--xml=your.file` in the project's options, under *Additional mtouch arguments*. That might be useful when you can't change the source code of the assemblies -or- when you want/need to use a tool to generate the list of members to be preserved;
2. Use the new `Preserve(Type)` constructor. That allows you to add preserve instructions in a **different** assembly (e.g. your main .exe) which already has a reference to `Xamarin.iOS.dll` (so no need to define your own type). E.g.

`[assembly: Preserve (typeof (MyType), AllMembers = true)]`

Comment: Very cool!  I'm curious. Regarding the XML file, is there any documentation that explains the schema?

Comment: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/custom_linking/ or http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=man%3Amtouch(1)

Comment: This is clearly the way to go, I'll use the XML file and update the answer accordingly when I'm done.

Comment: Alright, this solution works, but there one situation where we can't get it to work. When we have another solution that is referenced and the file is linked from another non-monotouch solution. When we put a preserve attribute on it, it woks, but using the xml solution with the somplete type name doesn't work...

Comment: Not sure I understand, the XML should apply to the code being included in the .app bundle (it does not care about where it comes from). If you can create a small test case that shows the issue please file a bug at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and I'll have a look

Comment: Maybe I should explain better before posting a bug. I made a Preserve.xml file with <assembly> and <type> tags with a wildcard for type ("My.Namespace.*"). For the first assembly, it works flawlessly. for the second one, it doesn't work with the xml way, but it works when using a preserve attribute. The only difference between the two files, one is in the solution itself and the other one is  in the solution but is a linked file. I understand it's probably not a problem because it should be compiled in the assembly, but there's no other difference that I'm aware of.

Comment: Could it be related to our project not using the unified api? we are in classic right now...

Comment: Classic/unified should not matter (xml support comes from monolinker, which predates this by many years).

Comment: I ended up using the XML file with --xml=Preserve.xml, the problem was that if you only change this file, the project won't be rebuilt. I had troubles using it because it was not preserving half my types. I simply forgot to rebuild. Thanks for this.

Comment: Is it possible to preserve namespace with wildcard? for example, I want to preserve all namespaces starts with myApp. So I have classes under myApp namespace and also myApp.Helpers namespace. Do you know if it it cover myApp.Helpers namespace if i just use myApp namespace?

Comment: Namespaces, by themselves, do not really exists as metadata, they are part of the type, so you can't use attributes on them. As for the XML I don't recall  if it's supported (easy to try), I never tried it (namespace) and I did not wrote the XML code.

Comment: I would like to preserve all classes with all members written by me in XF project but i have so many. what can be the easiest way to achieve this without adding preserve attribute in each class? or add each in xml

Comment: By default, **linksdk**, the linker does not eliminate user code, so you should be fine without any change. If you use **linkall** then you can still use `--linkskip=MyAssembly` to tell the linker not be remove anything from `MyAssembly.dll`. If you need control inside an assembly then you need the `[Preserve]` attribute or use an XML file to detail your requirements.

Comment: where do you define this --linkskip=MyAssembly in Android project? Is it good to define entire User assembly to be skipped also? by the way yes namespace is working like as i wrote above. I have just tested.

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is create a file called LinkerPleaseInclude.cs.  You can actually name it what you want, but this name makes sense.  In there you can create dummy objects for the types you need, especially for reflection.  That way the link will see that you "need" it and won't strip it out.  Here's an [example of a LinkerPleaseInclude.cs](https://github.com/aritchie/acrmvvmcross/blob/master/Sample.iOS/LinkerPleaseInclude.cs) file.  It's useful if the classes you need are defined in a 3rd party DLL.

**Update:**

Ah, I misread your original post thinking you were talking about 3rd party DLLs you have no control over.  So if you have a non-xamarin.iOS library, you can still use the Preserve attribute.  However, you will have to define it like so in your library project.:

```
public sealed class PreserveAttribute : System.Attribute 
{
    public bool AllMembers;
    public bool Conditional;
}
```

It doesn't which namespace you define the Preserve class in, as the linker only searches for the Preserve name.  Then you can just use the Preserve attribute as you normally would.  So if you want to Preserve a class and all 50 properties, then you do something like:

```
[Preserve(AllMembers=true)]
public MyClass
{
   //code here
}
```

Comment: That's actually pretty cool, I guess it's a good workaround for now, but are you aware of some way I could use this for an entire class without specifying all the attributes? I have a class that has more than 50 Properties... Thanks for this though.

Comment: Is this a DLL that you have written or a 3rd party DLL you have no control over?

Comment: Both! There's a 3rd party DLL and solution references to a windows solution.

Comment: Update: amazing, if it's actually checking for the preserve class without it being the specific mono class, that would solve everything.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone that uses Reflection to set Properties of UIKit Views here is my "Bread and Butter" Preserve Configuration.

Just create a new class in your Xamarin iOS App project and call it something like "LinkerGuard.cs" or "PreserveConfiguration.cs"

Put this in it:

```
using CoreAnimation;
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;


[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIResponder), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIControl), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIView), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIButton), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UILabel), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIImageView), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UITextField), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UISwitch), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIActivityIndicatorView), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIDatePicker), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIScrollView), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIWebView), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIPageControl), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIToolbar), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIStepper), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UISegmentedControl), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UISearchBar), AllMembers = true)]

[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIScreen), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIWindow), AllMembers = true)]

[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIBarItem), AllMembers = true)]

[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UINavigationBar), AllMembers = true)]


[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UITabBar), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UITabBarItem), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIBarButtonItem), AllMembers = true)]

[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UITextFieldCondition), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIViewContentMode), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UITextAlignment), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment), AllMembers = true)]

[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIReturnKeyType), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIDataDetectorType), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIKeyboardType), AllMembers = true)]

[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UITextFieldChange), AllMembers = true)]

[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UITableView), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UICollectionView), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UITableViewCell), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UICollectionViewCell), AllMembers = true)]

[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UITableViewDataSource), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UICollectionViewDataSource), AllMembers = true)]

[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIViewController), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UITabBarController), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UINavigationController), AllMembers = true)]

[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIDocument), AllMembers = true)]


[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UITapGestureRecognizer), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIGestureRecognizer), AllMembers = true)]

[assembly: Preserve (typeof (CGColor), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIColor), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIFont), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (UIImage), AllMembers = true)]

[assembly: Preserve (typeof (NSObject), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (NSAttributedString), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (NSLayoutConstraint), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (CAKeyFrameAnimation), AllMembers = true)]
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (NSIndexPath), AllMembers = true)]
```

Comment: I got `Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'conditional' of 'PreserveAttribute.PreserveAttribute(bool, bool)' `

Comment: @Felix That's the wrong `Preserve()`. Note the `using Foundation;` in the example above. You probably picked the one provided by `Xamarin.Forms.Internals`. (I know I'm late, but it might help others.)